# How can I tell how many times something is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to listen for something being clicked x number of times.

How can I do this?

There will be two elements on the page and I will listen for clicks on both.

What I am trying to do in pseudo-code is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#element1').click(function(){
       //do something to confirm click
    });
    $('#element2').click(function(){
        //do something to confirm click of element 2
    });

    if(element1.numberOfTimesClicked() == 2)
        //do something
    if(element2.numberOfTimesClicked() == 4)
        //do something
});
```

While I was typing the above, I realised how I would do this is have a counter variable and increment that on each click and then compare the counter variable's value to a number.

Is that a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var counter = 0;
$('#element1').click(function(){
   counter++;
});
```